# "Неизвестно" — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно

В каких случаях "неизвестно" пишется слитно, а в каких - раздельно?

Comment: @Galina_D, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 6):

Слова категории состояния на -о (так называемые предикативные наречия) пишутся с частицей  ***не*** слитно при утверждении: нетрудно видеть и *(***неизвестно утверждается неизвестность -*** **прим. - мое.**)* *раздельно* при отрицании: не трудно видеть (***не известно отрицается "известность";*** смысл обычно устанавливается самим пишущим). Русский язык. Справочник-практикум: Орфография. Пунктуация. Стр.111. Розенталь Д. Э.

Answer (score 5):

Если после этого слова подразумевается вопрос (косвенный), то пишем слитно. Например: "Неизвестно, когда я смогу уйти с работы". Это же касается и утверждений: "Орудие, которым было совершено преступление, неизвестно".
Раздельно пишется "не известно" в сочетании с наречиями "еще", "с тех пор", "пока" и "уже". Например, "Еще не известно, стоит ли выходить из дома".
Также раздельно надо писать, когда есть усилительные наречия: "далеко", "вовсе", "совсем", "ничуть" и т.д. Например: "О том, почему вымерли динозавры, нам совсем не известно". И тут еще совет: пробуйте между "не" и "известно" вставить слово. Если вставляется, значит, точно пишется раздельно: "Нам не известно, куда он пошел" - "Нам не до конца известно, куда он пошел".

Comment: Большое спасибо!
Но всё же вышел спор...
Было выражение: "Не известно, что там будет за платье."
Выходит, что здесь как раз подразумевается вопрос (косвенный),  поэтому надо писать слитно.
С другой стороны, можно между "не" и "известно" вставить слово, например: "Не до конца известно, что там будет за платье." Т.е. в данном случае пишем раздельно.
Как быть?????????????? Спасибо.